# Connect to API using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, web-scraping, curl

I need help to get authorization to connect to an API. The command line given is

```
curl -X GET "https://app.mysite.fr/api/v1/societe/11111111" -H "Authorization: Bearer 84dcc64aefabcdefghebcf7762752xx"
```

Below is my code written in VBA in ms-access

```
Function GetAuthorization()
    
    Dim objCurlHttp As Object
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim varReqToken As Variant
    Dim strWebServiceUrl As String
    Dim strOwnerKey As String
    Dim strQry As String
    
    strWebServiceUrl = "https://app.mysite.fr/api/v1/societe/11111111"
    strOwnerKey = "84dcc64aefabcdefghebcf776275xx"
    
    Set objCurlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
                                                          
    
    With objCurlHttp
        .Open "GET", strWebServiceUrl, False
        
        .SetRequestHeader "cache-control", "no-cache"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "Accept"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + strOwnerKey
        .Send
        
        strResult = .ResponseText
        Debug.Print strResult
    End With
    
    Set objCurlHttp = Nothing
    
End Function
```

This result is

> ? GetAuthorization()
> Unauthorized

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why all the weird headers? The curl code doesn't have those. Try only setting the authorization header. And ideally, you'd switch to using WinHTTP, MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP has some oddities due to sharing config/cookies with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reveal the documentation, but I seriously doubt that it states the *Accept* header as shown. So try:

```vb
        .Open "GET", strWebServiceUrl, False
        
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + strOwnerKey
```

Comment: Thanks it woks i got the authorization, but it is HTML and not json